# f:validateRegex doesn't show any message after typing invalid character

Tags: regex, jsf

I'm using JSF. With code for validating:

```
<h:inputText id="sender" value="#{contactForm.sender}">
      <f:validateRegex pattern="([a-zA-Z_0-9]).{4,32}" />
</h:inputText>
```

When i type a string: abc. The result is invalid. Good.
Then i type: abcd@ . I thought, that string is invalid because that string contains @ letter. But i don't recieve any messages. That means that string is valid. I don't understand about regex clearly. Can you help?

Comment: In regex, `.` mean any character, including `@`.  If you want a literal period, use `\.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape the `.` meta-character which matches any character in the input string

```
([a-zA-Z_0-9]).{4,32}
//            ^
//            |
//            |
//        Notice the dot . this matches any character
```

So you regular expression will match any string starting with lowercase, uppercase character or an underscore `_` or a number between `0` and `9` followed by any character repeated between 4 and 32 times, so this almost matches anything.

To fix this you have to escape the the dot `.` and include in the first group, something like the following, *- of course you can use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` as they are the same thing too -*:

```
([\w\.]){4,32}
```

The `.` dot has to go inside the group or the expression will match any string starting with the same as before but then contains between 4 and 32 dots, whereas now it will match any string that contains alphabetical characters or numbers or dots or underscores with a length between 4 and 32 characters.

Answer (score 2):

`<f:validateRegex>` is not for client side but for server side. Post a `<h:messages>` and send the form that contains this `<h:inputText>` to see the generated message for the wrong value for your `sender` component.

Example:

```
<h:form>
    Input the data:
    <h:inputText id="sender" value="#{contactForm.sender}">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="([a-zA-Z_0-9]).{4,32}" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

As suggested by BalusC in comments, you can fire the validation using ajax for the `onkeyup` event for your input.

```
<h:form>
    Input the data:
    <h:inputText id="sender" value="#{contactForm.sender}">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="([a-zA-Z_0-9]).{4,32}" />
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="messageId" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message id="messageId" for="sender" />
</h:form>
```

Also, as DavidStarkey posted in comment, your regex matches with `abcd@`. If you want to use a dot (`.`) as part of your regexp, use a backslash (`\`) prior to it:

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="([a-zA-Z_0-9])\.{4,32}" />
```

More info:

- [mkyong JSF 2 validateRegex example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-validateregex-example/)
- [Regex Tutorial: The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Comment: Or just bring in `<f:ajax event="keyup" render="messageId" />` so that it's validated on every keyup. But after all, I believe this is not OP's concrete problem.

Comment: Sorry for making you misunderstand. I knew and i used h:message. That snippet code is just used for my question about regex. Thanks for answer

Comment: @LostHeaven0809 I think it would be better if you post an example of the accepted and rejected strings for your input so we can help you define the regexp