# Not allow special characters and only upper case p:inputText Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Well, I have a `<p:inputText>` in primefaces, but I want know how can I allow only uppercase word and no special characters. Ex: Renato Calhaça = RENATO CALHACA

Comment: Do you want to only allow uppercase letters or do you want to convert all letters to uppercase?

Comment: Looks like you must apply a JavaScript function on your `onkeypress` event or use a regex validator that fires with ajax as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18384495/1065197)

Comment: KidTempo, I wanna to convert all letters to uppercase, just permit uppercase and words with no special characters.

Comment: You're not clear in your concrete functional requirement. In your previous comment you basically said that you want to convert lowercase to uppercase, but then you basically say that you want to validate ("permit") that the input is all uppercase. That are two completely different things. What exactly do you want? E.g. when the enduser enters "föó", what do you want JSF do to? Validate and show error so that enduser has to fix itselves? Or convert silently to "FOO" and proceed using converted value without showing error?

Answer (score 2):

you can add in your inputText

```
<p:inputText onblur="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
```

and in your css include at the end

```css
.ui-inputtext, .ui-inputfield{
    text-transform: uppercase;    
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
if you use primefaces 6+ you can use the component p:keyFilter

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyFilter.xhtml

```
<p:inputText id="text1">
    <p:keyFilter regEx="/[ABC]/i"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

`"Renato".toUpperCase()` will convert the string to uppercase.

Take a look at `java.text.Normalizer` for converting (some, not all) accented characters to standard.

To disallow lowercase and/or special characters then you should use a validator. A simple regex will identify special characters `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` or special and lowercase characters `[^A-Z0-9]`. The validator can also modify the input using the two methods indicated above - though you may want to make sure the user knows this is happening.

Comment: Looks like OP's asking about how to handle this in the view i.e. in client side, not in server side.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I actually cannot find that requirement anywhere in his question or comments. The user may enter it in lowercase, a converter will convert it to upper case and the validator will check it. Can be completely done server side and I don't see any reason to do it clientside.

Comment: I thnk that use p:validatorRegex a good solution, because i can permit only letters uppercase in this case.